# XAML to powershell

Tags: powershell

Im a beginner and is needing help running an XAML into powershell. 
Im trying to follow some format from the net but cant seem to convert my xaml GUI to powershell.
Any help will do. Heres my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Strike Email" Height="137" Width="274" Background="White">
<Grid Background="#FF005D80">
    <Button Content="1st Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="3rd Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="180,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White"/>
    <Button Content="2nd Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="95,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, you will need to:

- Cast your xaml string as a xml
- Load presentationframework assembly
- Load the XAML into a xmlNodeReader
- Load the form

Powershell must be running in STA (Single threaded) mode for this to work 
(Powershell ISE launch in STA mode by default.)

```
[xml]$xaml = 'ValidXAMLStringHere'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Something like the snippet would be the end result.
I even added a button click event for fun.

```
[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Strike Email" Height="137" Width="274" Background="White">
<Grid Background="#FF005D80">
    <Button Content="1st Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White" x:Name="FirstStrike" />
    <Button Content="3rd Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="180,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White"/>
    <Button Content="2nd Strike" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="95,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Background="White"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
'@

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 

try
{
        $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."t
}
cls
$Button = $Form.FindName('FirstStrike')
$Button.Add_Click({ Write-Host "First Strike Button Clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})


$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

**References:**

[Technet - Integrating XAML into PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/platformspfe/2014/01/20/integrating-xaml-into-powershell/)

[Learn Powershell - PowerShell and WPF: Buttons](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/01/powershell-and-wpf-buttons/)

Comment: Its perfect! Just what as I needed! Thank you so much!